# how to create Multiple user control that pointing single code behind file in silverlight 4

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, user-controls

I am creating a application, in which i have 2 user control, 
is it possible that, we have 2 xaml user control page and having 1 code behind xaml.cs file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start off by creating three files, first the "code-behind" .cs file is created as a simple class:-

```
 public class MyCommonUserControl : UserControl
 {

 }
```

Note it has no `InitializeComponent` call.

Now create a new `UserControl` then modify its xaml to look like this:-

```
<local:MyCommonUserControl x:Class="YourApp.FirstMyCommonUserControl "
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

    </Grid>

</local:MyCommonUserControl >
```

Note the addition the `xmlns:local` alias to point to your app's namespace then the change of the `UserControl` tag to the base control we actually want.

You would modify the .xaml.cs to this:-

```
public partial class FirstMyCommonUserControl : MyCommonUserControl 
{
    public FirstMyCommonUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

That is all the .xaml.cs needs to contain.

You can then repeat this for `SecondMyCommonUserControl` and so on.  Place all the common code in the base `MyCommonUserControl` class.

Its a pity MS didn't anticipate this in the first place, adding an empty virtual InitializeComponent method to the underlying `UserControl` and having the .g.i.cs auto-generated code `override` the method would have meant that we could dispense with this superflous .xaml.cs file in these cases.