# How to add functionality to an inherited property?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm following the instructions at this post: [how to create Multiple user control that pointing single code behind file in silverlight 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516211/how-to-create-multiple-user-control-that-pointing-single-code-behind-file-in-silv)

This is an example from my code.

```
public class MyCommonUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty CustomProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CustomProperty", typeof(int), typeof(MyCommonUserControl));

     public int CustomProperty
     {
         get
         {  
             return (int)GetValue(TypeProperty);
         }
         set
         {
             SetValue(TypeProperty, value);
             Extension();
         }
     }

     public virtual void Extension()
     {
     }
}

public class FirstMyCommonUserControl : MyCommonUserControl 
{
     public FirstMyCommonUserControl()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     public override void Extension()
     {
         base.Extension();

         // Do something
     }
}
```

As you can see above, I'm using inheritance. This code works for me, because I've got several custom controls, one of them is FirstMyCommonUserControl class which is overriding the virtual method and I can add some stuff for this particular class. Then I do this:

```
    MyCommonUserControl A;
    int number;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        switch (number)
        {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                A = new FirstMyCommonUserControl();
                A.CustomProperty = number;

                canvas1.Children.Add((FirstMyCommonUserControl)A);
                break;
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
                A = new AnotherMyCommonUserControl();
                A.CustomProperty = number;

                canvas1.Children.Add((AnotherMyCommonUserControl)A);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Each particular class needs to do something more in CustomProperty. I made it using virtual methods and overriding it. I don't know if doing this is the best way.

Comment: If all you're doing is performing additional actions when a dependency property is set (or changed), you should just register a value changed handler for the property.  No need to explicitly make it `virtual` or change the basic behavior.

Comment: Indeed. In fact with dependency properties you even **should not** do anything in the CLR-wrapper, see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) for information on why this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties can also be virtual, not only methods. So you could write something like

```
public class MyCommonUserControl : UserControl
{     
    public virtual int CustomProperty     
    {         
        get { return (int)GetValue(TypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TypeProperty, value); }
    }
}

public class FirstMyCommonUserControl : MyCommonUserControl 
{
    public override int CustomProperty     
    {         
        get 
        { 
            // Do something
            return base.CustomProperty;
        }
        set 
        { 
            // Do something
            base.CustomProperty = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Although whether or not is this *better* is debatable.

Also, there is no need for a cast in this expression of yours:

```
canvas1.Children.Add((FirstMyCommonUserControl)A);
```

You can just write:

```
canvas1.Children.Add(A);
```

Comment: Thank you! Boris did the trick, appreciate the help. Only two more questions, how did you know there's no need for a cast? and is there a possibility that I can change the data type in the override property?

Comment: @oscar.fimbres : #1 - There is no need for a cast because the Add method accepts a UIElement (or something, not sure) which is much lower in the inheritance chain than MyCommonUserControl. #2 You can't change the return type of a virtual property. You *could* declare it returning an `object`, but in that case you should rethink your design :). Also, my solution is about solving your problem in general, but for your specific need (DependancyProperty) you might look into what Jeff Mercado and H.B. suggested in comment to your quesition.