# Base class for Views in Navigation Application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, view, base-class

Trying to create a base class for my Views in my Silverlight 4 Business Application so that common methods are available throughout my application.  Unfortunately, doing this causes the following error:

**Partial declarations of 'SomeApp.Views.Home' must not specify different base classes**

It appears that Silverlight is creating another partial class for this View.  Is there a way to get this to work?

I tried to specify the Subclass as follows in the XAML of the View:

**x:Subclass="SomeApp.Views.PageBase"**

This did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes "Sivlerlight" is creating another partial class (actual its Visual Studio / MSBuild that is doing it).  When you save a .xaml file that has the build action "Compile" a dynamic .g.i.cs file is created.  It contains a partial class that matches the `x:Class` property and derives from the class represented by the top level node in the Xaml.

Hence xaml like this:-

```
 <UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MyControl" ... />
```

Will generate a MyControl.g.i.cs containing something like:-

```
 namespace SilverlightApplication1 {
     public partial class MyControl : System.Windows.Controls. UserControl {

    ....
```

The code-behind file must match.

Hence if you are creating a new base class to derive from, your top-level element must match the base class.

```
<local:PageBase xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomeApp.Views" x:Class="SomeApp.Views.Home" ... />
```

See also: [how to create Multiple user control that pointing single code behind file in silverlight 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516211/how-to-create-multiple-user-control-that-pointing-single-code-behind-file-in-silv)