# "InitializeComponent" does not exist -error when changing the codebehind file for a .xaml page

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, code-behind, initializecomponent

I have multiple xaml pages that have common functionality and I need to create a single .cs file to use them. So I commented all the code in my .cs for the .xaml and created a new .cs file to handle my "Test" page's functionality.

I followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516211/how-to-create-multiple-user-control-that-pointing-single-code-behind-file-in-sil) but I'm getting the error:

```
  "The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context "
```

as well as:

```
The type 'local:MainCode' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
```

Here's what I did:

In my .xaml page:

```
<**local:MainCode** x:Class="SilverlightApp1.Common.Test"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
**xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApp1.Common**"
```

And in my code page:

> namespace SilverlightApp1.Common {
>
> ```
> public class MainCode: UserControl
> {
>     public MainCode()
>     {
>     }
>
>     public partial class Test: MainCode
>     {
>         public Test()
>         {
>             InitializeComponent();
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```

Can you help point me to the problem ?

Comment: Quacks like an indenting mistake.  It is a nested class right now, its name is `SilverlightApp1.Common.MainCode.Test`.  So yes, that's going to make it complain about `SilverlightApp1.Common.Test`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried this but it produced an error "The namespace 'SilverlightApp1.Common' already contains a definition for 'MainCode' for the Test.g.cs file . What is causing this ?

Comment: Delete the fiels from your debug folder and try to rebuild again